# Weird pow() php bug

Tags: php

I have this piece of php code:

```
$skill_amount = round(pow($rarity,1.25));
```

It should be noted that $rarity is derived from a query.

I am inputting values like 0,2,4,8,16,32,64 into it.

99% of the time it is working but a small amount of times my users are reporting huge values like:

13771, 77936

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Do you know the value of $rarity when this occurs? pow() will convert all input to numbers, if $rarity would be something else this could lead to unexpected output.

Comment: Are you sure that `$rarity` is always a scalar and an integer? I might add some validation code on that variable to make sure that's the case. The PHP manual has this note on the `pow` function: _This function will convert all input to a number, even non-scalar values, which could lead to **weird** results._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"What could possibly be causing this?"
```

A large or unexpected value for `$rarity`.

If you can inspect all possible values of $rarity, you should do that. Otherwise, you could do some basic debugging.

```
if ($skill_amount > some sane value) {
    // log $skill_amount & $rarity to a file or email
    // maybe also some other investigative values, like stuff that assisted the derivation of $rarity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No trouble found in this script, so I would agree with the need for sanity checks on $rarity.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_amy_neville.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

$range = range(1, 4096);
foreach ($range as $rarity)
{
    $skill_amount = round(pow($rarity,1.25));
    $out[$rarity] = $skill_amount;
}
print_r($out);
```